# Swing components move as TextArea filled, in Scala

Tags: swing, panel, scala-swing

I'm having a basic issue with alignment in a BoxPanel.  When either of the TextAreas takes input, the other components in the panel, that aren't the width of the panel, shift along with the characters.

What is my mistake?  Thanks!

[image: blank TextArea]

[image: filled TextArea]

```
val exitButton = new Button {
  text = "Exit"
  borderPainted = true
  enabled = true
}

val japaneseTranslation = new TextArea(5, 25)
val englishTranslation = new TextArea(5,25)

val translationPanel = new BoxPanel (Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += new Label {
    text = "Translation"
    font = new Font("Ariel", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 20)
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Center
  }

  contents += new Label {
    text = "Japanese"
    font = new Font("ariel", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 10)
  }

  /*contents += new TextField ("Japanese") {                                                                                                                  
    editable = false                                                                                                                                          
  }*/
  contents += japaneseTranslation


  contents += new Label {
    text = "English"
    font = new Font("ariel", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 10)
  }
  contents += englishTranslation

  contents += exitButton

}
```

Comment: Assuming that `BoxPanel` is based on Swing's `BoxLayout` you may want to set `setAlignmentX` on both `japaneseTranslation` and `englishTranslation` to `Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT`. Not sure what is the equivalent of this constant in Scala.

Comment: Did you test the solution provided below? Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Aqua that was a helpful lead, thanks.  `peer.setAlignment...` as in Simon's answer is the working equivalent in Scala, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the `TextArea` components into a `ScrollPane` helps:

```
val exitButton = new Button {
  text = "Exit"
  borderPainted = true
  enabled = true
}

val japaneseTranslation = new TextArea(5, 25)
val englishTranslation = new TextArea(5,25)

val translationPanel = new BoxPanel (Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += new Label {
    text = "Translation"
    font = new Font("Ariel", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 20)
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Center
  }

  contents += new Label {
    text = "Japanese"
    font = new Font("ariel", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 10)
  }

  /*contents += new TextField ("Japanese") {                                                                                                                  
    editable = false                                                                                                                                          
  }*/
  contents += new ScrollPane(japaneseTranslation)


  contents += new Label {
    text = "English"
    font = new Font("ariel", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 10)
  }
  contents += new ScrollPane(englishTranslation)

  contents += exitButton

}
```

Another possibility is, as implied by Aqua in his comment, to set the alignmentX of your `TextArea` components:

```
val japaneseTranslation = new TextArea(5, 25) {
  peer.setAlignmentX(0)
}
val englishTranslation = new TextArea(5,25) {
  peer.setAlignmentX(0)
}
```

Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) next time.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Both solutions fix the problem completely.  Aqua's solution looked promising and I tried to implement it, but did not find `peer`.  I will post a SSCCE next time.  Thanks!